# Unable to replace the class of div element - no method named css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the old class of html element with the new one using jQuery. Here is what I'm doing:

```
var elem = $('.my_selector')[0];
elem.css('class', 'my_new_class');
```

But I get the error saying "Uncaught type error: `Object#<HtmlDivElement> has no method css`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Also, take note that `.css()` is technically the same as refering to an elements `style=""` attribute. So what you're doing is the following: `<div style="class: my_new_class"></div>`. Use `.prop('class', 'my_new_class')` or `addClass`/`removeClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call jQuery method `css()` (even not relevant here) from DOM element, which is derived with `[0]`. You can use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to do the job:

```
$(".my_selector:first").toggleClass("my_selector my_new_class");
```

Comment: This is close, however it will remove the my_selector class, which the OP didn't say he wanted to do. That may cause problems for him later.

Comment: @colestrode *"I want to replace the old class of html element with the new one using jQuery"*. Not that close?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... I missed that the first time I read it.

Comment: do I have to use my_selector as a parameter of toogleClass?

Comment: @AlanDert Yeah, if you want to remove `my_selector` class.

Comment: @AlanDert You just send a string of classnames seperated by spaces `class1 class2 class3 ...`. the toggleClass will toggle each of the classes. So for you, you send one parameter a string `"my_selector my_new_class"`

Answer (score 2):

`$('.my_selector')[0]` is returning you a DOM element, not a jQuery Object. You'll also want to use the `addClass` method rather than `css`. To get the first element, you can use the `:first` pseudoselector.

So this should be what you are looking for:

```
$('.my_selector:first').removeClass('my_selector').addClass('my_new_class');
```

**EDIT** You can use either `removeClass`/`addClass` or `toggleClass`. Either are fine. Explicitly adding the new class may be safer if you have a case where an element can have both classes at the same time since `toggleClass` will remove both classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = $('.my_selector')[0];
```

This will return the DOM element, not a jQuery object.  Simply change it to this...

```
var elem = $('.my_selector');
```

To get just the first element that matches the selector, use this...

```
var elem = $('.my_selector').first();
```

Also, you have...

```
elem.css('class', 'my_new_class');
```

This is incorrect and should be changed to this...

```
elem.attr('class', 'my_new_class');
```

Comment: This will *never* fix the problem.

Comment: it will return the array of jquery objects each of whose has .my_selector. what if I want just pick up the first of them?

Comment: @AlanDert If you just want the first then you have options, but I'd recommend `var elem = $('.my_selector').first();`

Comment: This should be mentioned in the post, @Archer.

Comment: What's fastest? `$('.my_selector').first()` or `$('.my_selector:first')`? I can imagine the latter, as it wouldn't have to create an array of all the elements first, just to select the first one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why people upvote it? `$('.my_selector').first().css("class", "new_class")` **WILL NEVER WORK**.

Comment: @VisioN I've explained what is causing his error message, but to keep you happy I'll amend the answer to include the rest.

Comment: @Archer I consider that as *not a complete answer* as if you answer "you are using `css` method in a wrong way".

Comment: [Shouldn't `.prop` be used in 1.6+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @Archer Using `attr("class")` is wrong here, since it will remove all additional classes (if any) set to the element. `addClass` and `removeClass` (or simply `toggleClass`) is the best way to go `:)`

Comment: @VisioN That seems to be what OP wanted, though.

Comment: @VisioN That's what the OP wants.  If not then he can let us know himself :)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Well, the OP wants to remove the previously set class and add the new one. There is nothing mentioned if there are other class names used by the element. If not `.prop("className")` or `.attr("class")` will work. Otherwise not. My concern is that replacing all the attribute value is a bad practice here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
var elem = $(".my_selector");
elem.class("newclass");
```

otherwise you can do,

```
var elem = $(".my_selector");
elem.removeClass("my_selector");
elem.addClass("newclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".my_selector").removeClass('currentClass').addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score -1):

As said, you need the jquery object of the first element. A good method could be this:

```
$('.my_selector').first().css('class', 'my_new_class');
```

Moreover the method signature is `.css( propertyName, value )` so its intented to set a css property not to change a class. To do that you need to remove old class and add new one with `.removeClass` and `.addClass` respectively.

Answer (score -3):

<del>$($('.my_selector')[0]).css('class', 'my_new_class');</del>

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my_selector')[0].className = 'my_new_class';
```

Comment: Really?  Get a jQuery object, get the DOM element from it and then convert that back to a jQuery object???

Comment: Incredibly inefficient and totally unnecessary, see answer from Archer for the correct way to do this.

Comment: Not again. There are no `class` property for DOM element.

Comment: @VisioN do you mean no `class` for a `CSS2Properties`? (i do think so...)